# Getting Jquery Error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id in form validations

Tags: jquery

Following is my code of contact form but when I am trying to test it on just name Above error is occured

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#submit").click(function({

        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name =='')
      {
          alert("Please Enter Your name");
      }

        });               
    )};
</script>
<body>
<div id="mainform">
<h2></h2>
<!-- Required Div Starts Here -->
<form id="form">
<h3></h3>
<p id="returnmessage"></p>
<label>Name: <span>*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<label>Email: <span>*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<label>Contact No: <span>*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="contact" placeholder="10 digit Mobile no."/>
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" placeholder="Message......."></textarea>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Send Message"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After running this code getting following error in console. Googling everywhere but no solution found.Please help me.

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
    var name = $("#name").val();
```

Comment: Typo: you're missing a `)` after `function(` on your `click` function.

Comment: The `;` and the end of the dom ready callback is invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                if (name == '')
                {
                    alert("Please Enter Your name");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your brackets and braces are incorrect on the `#submit` click function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() { // note extra ) here
        // your code...
    });               
}); // swapped order of braces here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just correct closing brackets of `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){  // <---------- correct here also
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name =='')
        {
          alert("Please Enter Your name");
        }
      });               
    }); // <---------
</script>
```

Comment: There's a close reason which should be used for typographical errors.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That's true, but the OP should also be told why it is a typographical error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan mine and Arun P Johny's comments on the question already do this.

Comment: Actually they don't because you missed another error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan then add that yourself as a comment on the question? These answers are unnecessary as this question will never help future users.